# What language/framework is most simiar to Salesforce development?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc, salesforce, visualforce

I hope it won't be marked as opinionated or too vague, but here's my quick story and question:

I started my development adventure in ASP.NET WebForms, just to move to Salesforce (Apex + Visualforce) soon after. I'm pretty decent SF Developer now with a few years of experience, but sometimes I'd like to be able to do some projects on the more open platform.

**So my question is: which of modern frameworks would be the closest to SF Dev and have the flattest learning curve for Salesforce developer with good Apex, Visualforce and Lightning knowledge?**

I know Apex is mostly Java-like, but adding framework, like Spring, makes it a lot different - like A LOT. The number of prerequisites just to start the Spring MVC project is huge.

The closest I think I've got is ASP.NET WebForms (even though SF boasts to be MVC framework and ASP.NET WebForms is not), but it seems to be dying off.

I looked at ASP.MVC, but again it's philosophy is more complicated than SF with a lot of magic happening during scaffolding and bootstrapping that is hard to follow.

Maybe .NET Core Razor Pages? This seems to be like a new kid on the block, pulling goodies from ASP.NET WebForms and ASP MVC worlds.

Are there any SF Devs that moved to or away from other framework and thought "wow, that's similar!"?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET with Razor markup is pretty similar to Apex with Visualforce (https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_intro.asp). But yes, controller side is a little bit different so you will need to learn this.

Do you like Lightning framework?
Maybe Angular then?

Comment: Thanks
Not sure if I like Lightning, but I know it pretty well. I poked around to find similar front-end framework and it seems that Angular 2+ is the closest from my newbie perspective.